# Summing up three data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sum three data frames and i want to sum based on a single column(hkd_margin) and it has to summed together based on account number.

The data frames look like this:

How do I do it? Need some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('account_number', as_index=False)['hkd_margin'].sum()
print (df)
   account_number    hkd_margin
0              20  2.361950e+05
1              40  1.375593e+07
2              60  2.174999e+07
3              90  4.695600e+04
```

Comment: I don't want the index to be 0,1,2,3. instead would like it to be the account_number. How do i do that?

Comment: @lakesh - Remove `as_index=False` from this solution for `Series`